# AngularJs Abort Previous service Call when New Call Performed

Tags: angularjs, service, autocomplete, material-design

I am using md auto complete for Auto Segessions. while I am entering text I want to make a server call to get the results. but I want to abort the previous server call, when I have to control that in controller script or in service script.?

```
<md-autocomplete flex required flex-gt-sm="25
      md-selected-item="school.college_name"
      md-clear-button="true"
      md-input-name="school.college"
      md-input-minlength="3"
      md-input-maxlength="40"
      md-no-cache="noCache"
      md-search-text="searchText"
      md-items="item in ctrl.academyschoolsList"
      md-search-text-change = "ctrl.searchAcademySchools(searchText)"
      md-item-text="item.name">

    <md-item-template>
        <span class="item-title">
            <span> {{item.name}}, {{item.city}}, {{item.state}}, {{item.zip}}
            </span>
        </span>
    </md-item-template>
    <div ng-messages="ctrl.leadEntryForm.school.college.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
    </div>
</md-autocomplete>
```

```
function searchAcademySchools(query) {
    ctrl.academyschoolsList = [];
    if (query.length > 3) {
        C2Services.getAcademySchools(query).then(function (data) {
            angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                ctrl.academyschoolsList.push(value);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the code in the question do when a new XHR is  started while one is already in progress? Does it push both results  to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XHR can't be aborted once it starts, but new results can replace old results:

```
function searchAcademySchools(query) {
    if (query.length > 3) {
        C2Services.getAcademySchools(query).then(function (data) {
            ctrl.academyschoolsList = data;
        });
    } else {
        ctrl.academyschoolsList = [];
    };
}
```

In this example each XHR will replace the old results.